# Marker show if marker inside polygon and should not be shown if outside polygon in googlemap

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

My Question is how to find lat long inside the drawn polygon or not i have mutliple records in my database , when app started then all markers visible and when we draw shape and apply then only marker inside the polygon show ,,this is very important for me please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried till now.

Answer (score 1):

This function determines whether a given point is inside a polygon:

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)
```

Here is a sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/v47a33cr/

If user clicks the rectangle (which is a polygon this time) the markers outside the polygon will be removed from the map.

Hope it helps.